# How to specify the number of CPU a container will use?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am on working on Windows Server 2019 and trying to run a docker container of CentOS on it. I am running the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run -dit --name=testing23 --cpu-shares=12    raycentos:1.0
6a3ffb86c1d9509a9d80f0de54fc6acf5731ca645ee74e6aabe41d7153b3af70
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker exec -it 6a3ffb86c1d9509a9d80f0de54fc6acf5731ca645ee74e6aabe41d7153b3af70 bash
(app-root) bash-4.2# nproc
2
```

It still specifies only 2, and not 32. How can we assign more CPUs to the container?

Answer (score 1):

refer to this topic for more details https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu

you have to add the values with proper flags

try :

```
    --cpus=<value> for maximum CPU resources a container can use
    --cpuset-cpus = 12
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: you are right, i deleted my comment and updated your answer.

Comment: Does not work                                                                          
      C:\Windows\system32> docker run -dit --name=testing23 --cpus=12 --cpuset-cpus=12   raycentos:1.0
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid option: Windows does not support CpusetCpus.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help'.
PS C:\Windows\system32>

Answer (score 0):

By default, all can be used, or you can limit it per container using the `--cpuset-cpus` parameter.

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-2" myapplication:latest
```

That would restrict the container to 3 CPU's (0, 1, and 2). See the [docker run docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint) for more details.

The chosen way to limit CPU usage of containers is with a fractional limit on CPUs:

```
docker run --cpus 2.5 myapplication:latest
```

Comment: Does not work C:\Windows\system32> docker run -dit --name=testing23 --cpus=12 --cpuset-cpus=12 raycentos:1.0 C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid option: Windows does not support CpusetCpus.

Comment: Try this docker run -it --name=testing23 --cpus=12

Comment: I did this  .. it runs but then when i check i still see 2 cpus    (app-root) bash-4.2# nproc
2

Comment: Try this --cpus=2.5 and check

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run -dit --name=testing23  --cpus=2.5  raycentos:1.0
ba29040cbdd2d3ed195aaac53504758de7b313356ddadded249ad00809acc0bc
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker exec -it ba29040cbdd2d3ed195aaac53504758de7b313356ddadded249ad00809acc0bc bash

(app-root) bash-4.2# nproc
2

Comment: i am on docker on windows server 2019 . is there a provision to provide the total number of cpus to docker service as a whole and not to each container .. there is no docker desktop    for windows server  machine

Comment: if you run docker inside of a VM, including Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, and docker-machine, those VM's will have a CPU limit separate from your laptop itself. Docker runs inside of that VM and will use all the resources given to the VM itself

Comment: try to increase your VM cpu-count first and then use --cpuset-cpus option to increase your docker cores

Comment: sir , how to do that . i am on windows server 2019 machine and there is NO VM that i am using .. i just enabled docker from  powershell and started using it .    should i install somethin ?